# What's a good "mobile" .NET database that supports LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, embedded-database

I'm in the process of refactoring an application and I've decided to use a mobile/embedded database.

I've been reading about SQL Server Compact Edition, but I was wondering if any of you knew of any other databases that could be used and don't have huge download sizes, as my current application is about ~2MB (installer). SQLite would be nice, but AFAIK the GSoC implementation of LINQ-to-SQLite is rather buggy at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Is SQL Server Express Edition an option? Or it's not since it's not really mobile in the truest sense?

Comment: Not really... would be too much for a 2MB application. I'm really looking for SQL Server CE alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/) and (as you mentioned) [Sql Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact-downloads.aspx) are two small options for an embedded database. Sql Server Compact Edition can be used with Linq to SQL or Entity Framework. I believe VistaDB can be used with the Entity Framework.

Also, if you do not require a relational database, you may want to consider [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/). Rob Conery writes about this [here](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/crazy-talk-reducing-orm-friction/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

I have tried out db40 once (not the compact edition) - it is an object database. However, depending on your needs it may be a rather comfortable thing to use. They note that they support linq even for the compact edition:
http://www.db4o.com/s/compactframeworkdb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but you might want to look at [BlackFish](http://www.codegear.com/products/blackfish). I'm not sure about its Linq support though, but Delphi supports Linq so it may. Another may be [Embedded Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/blog/2005/02/embedded-firebird-and-microsoft-sql.html) - again, not sure about the Linq side of things.