# c# embeded database easy dao model

Tags: c#, .net, database

For my application I need an embedded database. 
I don't have a lot of data in the database and performance is not an issue. 
My first concern is to be able to access the data easily (LinqToSQL) or some active record model. I need this in order to invest as little as possible in the data access layer. 
Another requirement will be to be able to brose the data through sql server manager.

If the database supports unique constraints this will be great.

Can you recommend me some alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .Net 4.0, you can use SQL CE and Entity Framework. (Code first approach will be good.) Here is the link about Code First development.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer:
[What's a good "mobile" .NET database that supports LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423452/whats-a-good-mobile-net-database-that-supports-linq)

There are also object databases you can use:

Perst: http://www.mcobject.com/perst

Siaqodb: http://siaqodb.com/